# Elasticsearch - Limit results per page per field

Tags: elasticsearch

We are using ElasticSearch for our filter system.
Our shop has products from several brands and we want to display more diversified results.
It is really weird to see products from the same brand as the first 20 results while we want to display other brands as well.

In the current output we are soring based on `product_score` this is also should be taken into the consideration.

Our Documents:

```
[
        {
            "id": 1,
            "brand_id": 1,
            "product_score": 100
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "brand_id": 1,
            "product_score": 99
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "brand_id": 1,
            "product_score": 97
        },
        {
            "id": 4,
            "brand_id": 1,
            "product_score": 96
        },
        {
            "id": 5,
            "brand_id": 2,
            "product_score": 80
        },
        {
            "id": 6,
            "brand_id": 2,
            "product_score": 40
        },
        {
            "id": 7,
            "brand_id": 2,
            "product_score": 39
        },
        {
            "id": 8,
            "brand_id": 3,
            "product_score": 38
        },
        {
            "id": 9,
            "brand_id": 3,
            "product_score": 37
        },
        {
            "id": 10,
            "brand_id": 4,
            "product_score": 31
        }
    ]
```

Expected Result Page 1:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "brand_id": 1
    },
    {
        "id": 5,
        "brand_id": 2
    },
    {
        "id": 8,
        "brand_id": 3
    },
    {
        "id": 10,
        "brand_id": 4
    }
]
```

Expected Result Page 2:

```
[
    {
        "id": 2,
        "brand_id": 1
    },
    {
        "id": 6,
        "brand_id": 2
    },
    {
        "id": 9,
        "brand_id": 3
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "brand_id": 1
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

I reckon one could come up with a complex, parametrized [`function_score` query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-function-score-query.html) to do this but I think the following aggregation solution is easier to set up. Though a bit of client-side post-processing will be needed to prepare the response in the format you require.

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "by_brand": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "brand_id",             <-- make sure you always have distinct brands
        "order": {
          "top_score_anchor": "desc"     <-- order the enclosed buckets by product_score descending                   
        }                                  ^
      },                                   |
      "aggs": {                            |
        "top_score_anchor": {              |
          "max": {                         |
            "field": "product_score"     --> 
          }
        },
        "top_scored_products": {
          "top_hits": {                  <-- enables you to extract the corresponding bucket's id, brand, and score
            "sort": [
              {
                "product_score": {
                  "order": "desc"
                }
              }
            ],
            "from": 0,                   <-- pagination, starting at 0
            "size": 1
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Page 1 yields then

```
"aggregations" : {
  "by_brand" : {
    ...
    "buckets" : [
      {
        "key" : 1,                         
        ...
        "top_scored_products" : {
          "hits" : {
            ...
            "hits" : [
              {
               ...
                "_source" : {
                  "id" : 1,                <--
                  "brand_id" : 1,          <--
                  "product_score" : 100
                },
                ...
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "key" : 2,
        ...
        "top_scored_products" : {
          "hits" : {
            ...
            "hits" : [
              {
                ...
                "_source" : {
                  "id" : 5,                <--
                  "brand_id" : 2,          <--
                  "product_score" : 80
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "key" : 3,
        ...
        "top_scored_products" : {
          "hits" : {
            ...
            "hits" : [
              {
                ...
                "_source" : {
                  "id" : 8,
                  "brand_id" : 3,
                  "product_score" : 38
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "key" : 4,
        ...
        "top_scored_products" : {
          "hits" : {
            ...
            "hits" : [
              {
                ...
                "_source" : {
                  "id" : 10,
                  "brand_id" : 4,
                  "product_score" : 31
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

which, after the noted post-processing, corresponds to your desired

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "brand_id": 1
    },
    {
        "id": 5,
        "brand_id": 2
    },
    {
        "id": 8,
        "brand_id": 3
    },
    {
        "id": 10,
        "brand_id": 4
    }
]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer Joe, answer given using aggregator but we are seeking an option to limit result return in the filter context based on brand_id.